# Access to function on composite types from a trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have defined several functions on composite types to act like calculated fields, something like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION status_affaireannulee(affaires) RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS $BODY$
  SELECT COALESCE($1.affannulee,FALSE) OR $1.constatdecarence;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Here, `affaires` is the name of a table. So I can call :

```
SELECT a.status_affaireannulee FROM affaires a WHERE idaffaire=1234;
```

Now I wish to use this function from within an update trigger, like so :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION affaires_update_CaseProgress() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.status_affaireannulee THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'affaire annulée';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER affaires_caseprogress
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON affaires
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE affaires_update_CaseProgress();
```

But PostgreSQL tells me "Record « new » has no « status_affaireannulee » field" (free translation from french).

Am I doing something wrong or is this impossible? I am using PostgreSQL 11.

Comment: Unclear. [Edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statements for the type(s), table(s) and trigger(s) as well as sample data as `INSERT` statements, the statement that should trigger the trigger and how the data in the table(s) should look like after that statements as markdown table (see ["How can I create a table in a post?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)).

Comment: @stickybit Not sure you have read the question. I added the (useless) definition of the trigger. The table structure and data are completely irrelevant to my question (if you look at what the trigger function does you'll understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `NEW` parameter to the function instead of using the dot notation:

```sql
status_affaireannulee(NEW)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks !